# Faster smsurv function

Tags: r, performance

I am trying to make an R function (much) more efficient. Find a working example below.

```
    smsurv <- function(Time,Status,X,beta,w,model){    
    death_point <- sort(unique(subset(Time, Status==1)))
    if(model=='ph') coxexp <- exp((beta)%*%t(X[,-1]))  
    n <- length(death_point)
    lambda <- numeric(n)
    for(i in 1: n){
      if(model=='ph')  temp <- sum(as.numeric(Time>=death_point[i])*w*drop(coxexp))
      if(model=='aft')  temp <- sum(as.numeric(Time>=death_point[i])*w)
      lambda[i] <- sum(Status*as.numeric(Time==death_point[i]))/temp
    }
    HHazard <- numeric()
    for(i in 1:length(Time)){
      HHazard[i] <- sum(as.numeric(Time[i]>=death_point)*lambda)
      if(Time[i]>max(death_point))HHazard[i] <- Inf
      if(Time[i]<min(death_point))HHazard[i] <- 0
    }
    survival <- exp(-HHazard)
    list(survival=survival)
  }

nr_obs = 50000

Time_input <- rnorm(nr_obs, mean = 100, sd = 36)
Status_input <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=nr_obs)
w_input <- Status_input

# Let's suppose there are 9 variables (first column denotes the intercept)
n_variables <- 9
X_input <- matrix(rnorm(nr_obs*n_variables),nr_obs)
X_input <- cbind(Intercept = rep(1, nrow(X_input)), X_input) 

beta_input <- runif(n_variables, min = -1, max = 1)
model_input <- "ph"
output <- smsurv(Time_input,Status_input,X_input,beta_input,w_input,model_input)
```

I have already attempted to replace the for-loops with lapply and sapply, but this actually made the function even slower:

```
    smsurv2 <- function(Time,Status,X,beta,w,model){    
    death_point <- sort(unique(subset(Time, Status==1)))
    if(model=='ph') coxexp <- exp((beta)%*%t(X[,-1]))  
    if(model_input=='ph') lambda =unlist(lapply(death_point, function(z) sum(Status_input*as.numeric(Time_input==z))/ sum(as.numeric(Time_input>=z)*w_input*drop(coxexp))))
    if(model=='aft') lambda =unlist( lapply(death_point, function(z) sum(Status_input*as.numeric(Time_input==z))/ sum(as.numeric(Time_input>=z)*w_input)))
    HHazard <- unlist(lapply(Time, function(t) {sum(as.numeric(t>=death_point)*lambda)}))
    HHazard[Time > max(death_point)] <- Inf
    HHazard[Time < min(death_point)] <- 0

    survival <- exp(-HHazard)
    list(survival=survival)
  }

smsurv3 <- function(Time, Status, X, beta, w, model){
  death_point <- sort(unique(subset(Time, Status==1)))
  if(model=='ph') coxexp <- exp((beta)%*%t(X[,-1]))
  lambda <- sapply(death_point, function(dp) {return(sum(Status*as.numeric(Time==dp))/sum(as.numeric(Time>=dp)*w*drop(coxexp)))})
  HHazard <- sapply(Time, function(t){return(sum(as.numeric(t>=death_point)*lambda))})
  HHazard[Time > max(death_point)] <- Inf
  HHazard[Time < min(death_point)] <- 0

  survival <- exp(-HHazard)
  list(survival=survival)
}
```

With this in mind, does someone have any other suggestions that I can try? I recently read about the rcpp package, but I am not sure how to replace the for loops with C code. Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: If time is a continuous variable (`rnorm`), why the call to `unique`? The instruction `Status*as.numeric(Time==death_point[i])` should give all zeros except for ne time and the result is `Status[i]`.

Comment: The rnorm is just to provide some example code. The data that I am actually working with is also double, but has some duplicate values. I was thinking using unique saves at least a few iterations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Function `smsurv2` below is faster and the results identical to the question's function.

Here are some of the changes I have made.

- `subset` is slow, indexed subsetting is faster;
- I removed the computation of `coxexp` from the first `for` loop making the loop the code simpler, it will always multiply by `coxexp`, which can be a vector of 1's, removing the `if` tests;
- `seq_along` is safer than `1:n`;
- removed the assignments to `Inf` and 0 from the second loop, this can be vectorized outside the loop;
- `as.numeric` is never needed, several functions calls are thus eliminated.

```r
smsurv2 <- function(Time, Status, X, beta, w, model){
  death_point <- Time[Status == 1] |> unique() |> sort()
  n <- length(death_point)
  lambda <- numeric(n)
  if(model == 'ph') {
    coxexp <- (exp(beta %*% t(X[, -1]))) |> drop()
  } else if(model == 'aft') {
    coxexp <- rep(1, length(Time))
  }
  for(i in seq_along(death_point)){
    temp <- sum((Time >= death_point[i]) * w * coxexp)
    lambda[i] <- sum(Status * (Time == death_point[i])) / temp
  }
  HHazard <- numeric(length(Time))
  for(i in seq_along(Time)){
    HHazard[i] <- sum((Time[i] >= death_point) * lambda)
  }
  HHazard[ Time > max(death_point) ] <- Inf
  HHazard[ Time < min(death_point) ] <- 0
  survival <- exp(-HHazard)
  list(survival = survival)
}


nr_obs = 50000

Time_input <- rnorm(nr_obs, mean = 100, sd = 36)
Status_input <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=nr_obs)
w_input <- Status_input

# Let's suppose there are 9 variables (first column denotes the intercept)
n_variables <- 9
X_input <- matrix(rnorm(nr_obs*n_variables),nr_obs)
X_input <- cbind(Intercept = rep(1, nrow(X_input)), X_input) 

beta_input <- runif(n_variables, min = -1, max = 1)
model_input <- "ph"

system.time(
  output <- smsurv(Time_input,Status_input,X_input,beta_input,w_input,model_input)
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   25.08    4.95   33.39

system.time(
  output2 <- smsurv2(Time_input,Status_input,X_input,beta_input,w_input,model_input)
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   16.92    1.45   19.86

identical(output, output2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This answer has been linked from meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426696. Might explain why you got some downvotes on a very good answer.

Answer (score 7):

### Vectorize for a >600x speedup

The gist here is to use `cumsum` after sorting by `Time` to avoid the loops. Everything is then vectorized, and it runs almost instantly.

Since this question is getting so many views, I've added a lengthier explanation on why `for` loops here are so slow. Scroll to the bottom for that.

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

smsurv2 <- function(Time, Status, X, beta, w, model){
  list(
    survival = setorder(
      setorder(
        data.table(Time, Status)[,r := .I],
        -Time, Status
      )[
        ,`:=`(
          death_point = Time != shift(Time, -1L, Time[1] - 1) & Status,
          temp = cumsum((if (model=='ph') w*drop(exp(tcrossprod(beta, X[,-1]))) else w)[r]),
          lambda = cumsum(Status)
        )
      ][
        death_point == TRUE, lambda := c(lambda[1], diff(lambda))/temp
      ][
        death_point == FALSE, lambda := 0
      ][
        ,survival := exp(-rev(cumsum(rev(lambda))))
      ][
        seq_len(which.max(death_point) - 1L), survival := 0
      ][, c(1:2, 4:6) := NULL],
      r
    )[[2]]
  )
}
```

Compare timings using the OP's example data:

```
system.time({
  output <- smsurv(Time_input,Status_input,X_input,beta_input,w_input,model_input)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   36.19    4.97   42.89
system.time({
  output2 <- smsurv2(Time_input,Status_input,X_input,beta_input,w_input,model_input)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.07    0.00    0.07

all.equal(output, output2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

---

### Avoiding the `for` loops

Consider the first line in the first `for` loop:

```
if(model=='ph')  temp <- sum(as.numeric(Time>=death_point[i])*w*drop(coxexp))
```

Here, `death_point` is a vector of values taken from `Time`, and `w*coxexp` is a vector of values the same length (50000) as `Time`. This line is simply summing `w*coxexp` where the corresponding `Time` is greater than or equal to `death_point[i]`. This involves 50000 comparisons followed by two (vectorized) multiplications, and the result is summed. If `death_point` were of length 1, it would make sense to do it this way. However, `death_point` in the example is length 24920, so this **one line involves 50000*24920 ~ 1.25 billion comparisons!** Instead, we can in effect accomplish all those comparisons with a single *sort*: Put `Time` and the result of `w*coxexp` in a table, sort descending on `Time`, compute the cumulative sum of `w*coxexp`, then take the values at the times marked as `death_point`s. We now have all the values that `temp` will take, and we needed only two vectorized function calls (`setorder` and `cumsum`). All the other calculations in `smsurv2` are performed just as easily because the table is already sorted.